# How to test the connection to a db2 database

Tags: testing, connection, db2

I need to test the connection to a db2 database.

With oracle databases I'd execute a 'select * from dual' in order to do this.

But dual is specific for oracle. Is there a similar canonical test sql statement for db2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

cheaper then

`SELECT CURRENT SQLID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```
SELECT CURRENT SQLID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

which seems to work nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
LIST DB DIRECTORY
```

or

```
LIST TABLES
```

Comment: With these I get com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][10103][10941] Die Methode executeQuery kann nicht zur Aktualisierung verwendet werden. Which roughly translates to method "executeQuery" cann not be used for updates. (I'm using the jdbc executeQuery method