# How to use NOT EXISTS with COMPOSITE KEYS in SQL for inserting data from POJO

Tags: java, sql, database, db2, composite-key

I am using DB2 DBMS.

**Scenario 1:**

myTable has a composite key (key1, key2) where both key1 and key2 are foreign keys from yourTable.

I want to insert new data from yourTable into myTable, but only if the key1, key2 combination does not already exist in myTable.

```
insert into myTable(key1, key2, someData)
values(x, y, z)
where NOT EXISTS (want to check if composite key is not already present)
```

**Scenario 2:**

I put data into a java object from yourTable with properties data1, data2, and data.

I want to insert the above data with the check as in Scenario1. data1 + data2 should not already be present in myTable.

How do I achieve this? I don't think we can use a SELECT statement inside the insert statement.

```
insert into myTable(key1, key2, data)
values(data1, data2, data)
where (data1 + data2 are already not present in myTable)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What DBMS are you doing this on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
insert into mytable(...)
select ...
from yourtable y
left join mytable m
on y.key1 = m.key1 and y.key2 = m.key2
where m.key is null
```

or

```
insert into mytable(...)
select ...
from yourtable y
where not exists (select 1 from mytable m where y.key1 = m.key1 and y.key2 = m.key2)
```

for your 2nd scenario, it'd look similar to the above query

```
insert into mytable(...)
select ...
where not exists (select 1 from mytable m where javakey1 = m.key1 and javakey2 = m.key2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a new scenario where I believe above answers will not work!

Comment: insert into mytable(d1, d2, d) select d1,d2,d where not exists (select 1 from mytable m where javakey1 = m.key1 and javakey2 = m.key2;  ------   is this correct ???

Comment: yes, assuming d1, d2, and d in your select are values and not columns from a table (i.e. similar in nature to javakey1, javakey2)

Comment: Sorry. But not working. I created a table with three columns and first two columns as primary key. Inserted some rows. Now running "insert into NIK(DATA1, DATA2, DATA) select 'C','3','MY' where not exists (select 1 from NIK A where 'C' = A.DATA1 and '3' = A.DATA2;" as per your answer is giving syntax error

Comment: Do you have closing parenthesis on your not exists select?

Comment: @Nikunj - You need to correlate your `EXISTS` subquery - right now it doesn't relate to the outer query at all.

Comment: Yes. I have the closing parenthesis. Error is: DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'C','3','MY' where not exists" was found 
following "DATA2, DATA) select".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: This query works fine for me on one of my databases: select '1', '2', '3' where not exists (select 1 from account a where a.accountkey = '2')

Comment: @JNK: Can you please reply to the question showing me how. Thanks!!

Comment: @Derek Kromm: Are you able to run it with insert query similar to how I am trying ?

Comment: @Nikunj: Use `INSERT INTO ... select 'C','3','MY' **FROM dual** where not exists (select ...)`

Comment: @ypercube: insert into mySchema.NIK(DATA1, DATA2, DATA) select 'C','3','MY' FROM mySchema.DUAL where not exists (select 1 from NIK A where 'C' = A.DATA1 and '3' = A.DATA2) -- not working. SQL0204N  "EOD.DUAL" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704.

Comment: @Nikunj: `FROM dual`, not `FROM mySchema.DUAL`

Comment: I cannot test in DB2 but from what I know, MySQL and SQL-Server allow SELECT without FROM, while Oracle and DB2 have a special `Dual` table that has exactly one row and can be used for this.

Comment: And this answer suggests it's actually **`SYSIBM.DUAL`**  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951713/converting-a-db2-query-into-oracle-query

Comment: While this answer suggests there's a **`SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733356/how-to-test-the-connection-to-a-db2-database

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into mySchema.NIK(DATA1, DATA2, DATA) select 'C','3','MY' FROM SYSIBM.DUAL where not exists (select 1 from mySchema.NIK A where 'C' = A.DATA1 and '3' = A.DATA2)
```

if the data 'c' '3' already exists then above query will result in an empty table.