# Preceeding almost every call, we get a pretty useless call that comes in as a separate transaction SELECT CURRENT SQLID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

Tags: java, sql, db2, websphere, openjpa

We have a JAVA application that connects to DB2 throught openJPA to fetch data. Preceeding almost every SQL call, we get a pretty useless call that comes in as a separate transaction:
"**SELECT CURRENT SQLID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1**"

DBA says he doesn't have any idea why this above useless SQL statement gets called before almost every call.

Any idea why this query gets called? Is there anything I can do to skip this?

It's been a while I am stuck with this issue with DBA complaining about dramatically increment in the number of transaction hitting DB2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Probably a connection validation query executed by a connection pool implementation, to ensure the connection hasn't gone stale before being handed to the application code. See "[How to test the connection to a db2 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733356/how-to-test-the-connection-to-a-db2-database)".

Comment: See also "[DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10684244/5221149)" and "[What is a validationQuery with respect to databases and JNDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15393954/5221149)"

Comment: So it says Validation query is run by the data source to validate that a Connection is still open before returning it. Means by data source is by default running this query every time? Is there anyway I can limit this query because it is creating a overhead on DB2. It is over flooding DB2 and it is the main concern.

Comment: It only runs the validation when your app wants a connection anyway, but your app may run many statements on the same invocation. Since the validation query is a dummy, it takes no time to run, while app statements will do actual work that takes DB2 time to execute. *Worst case* scenario is that you get as many validation queries as other statements, though that's unlikely, and they are minuscule to the *work* DB2 has to do for the other statements.

Comment: Note that [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) (a commonly used pooling library) will call [`Connection.isValid()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid-int-) if no validation query is configured, and javadoc says: *The driver shall submit a query on the connection or use some other mechanism that positively verifies the connection is still valid when this method is called.* That is probably where the actual query is coming from: the DB2 JDBC driver.

Comment: Which WebSphere version are you using? If you have datasource configured in WAS, make sure that on  `Data sources > YOUR_DATASOURCE > WebSphere Application Server data source properties` page you have UNCHECKED both `Validate connections..` options.

Comment: I am using WAS7. I will check that for that configuration as you say. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me @Gas. I had to uncheck that property. Thanks a lot.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have datasource configured in WAS, make sure that on `Data sources > YOUR_DATASOURCE > WebSphere Application Server data source properties` page you have **UNCHECKED** both `Validate connections..` options.

Answer (score 0):

The query is coming from the connection pool manager, validating it before handing it over to the application. I think your connection pool implementation is at worst broken, at best misconfigured.

To begin with,

> The query submitted by the driver to validate the connection shall be executed in the context of the current transaction.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)

So if the validation query comes outside of your transaction, it's non-compliant.

Second, as of JDBC4, the connection pool implementation is not required to run a validation query, it can use other means of validating the connection isn't closed or stale. Check [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Configuration) configuration for the discussion on this topic. I can't give you guarantees that the pool manager you're using is capable of being configured differently, but certainly check it, and maybe check it with alternative pool managers.